# Using Lists / Arrays in MySQL when migrating from Postgres?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-migration, prisma

I am moving from Postgres to Mysql (using Prisma as my connector).

This schema used to work:

```
model Page {
  slug        String  @id
  someValue   String
  ...
  tags        String[]
}
```

However, mysql doesn't seem to like `String[]`

> Unable to get DMMF from Prisma Client:  Error: Schema parsing error:
> Field "tags" in model "Page" can't be a list. The current connector
> does not support lists of primitive types.

What am I supposed to do in mysql instead?

Comment: *What am I supposed to do in mysql instead?* Directly - JSON array.

Comment: Or just design a properly normalised database structure as you are using an rdbms

Comment: @Akina could you pls add the json array answer to the "Is there any array data type in MySQL like in PostgreSQL", so the possible answers are captured under one question?